# Django: Adding model to ManyToMany by pk, without fetching

Tags: python, django, orm

I have model A with a ManyToMany to model B. I have a pk of an object of model B, and I want to add it to the ManyToManyField of an object of model A. Is it possible to add it without expending resources to fetch object b from the database? I already have its pk, can I add it without fetching?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `add()`. Django knows that if it's a number instead of an object, to treat it as a primary key:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bars = models.ManyToMany('Bar')

class Bar(models.Model):
    ...


>>> foo = Foo.objects.latest('id') #arbitrary
>>> target_pk = 5
>>> 
>>> # method 1:
>>> bar = Bar.objects.get(pk=target_pk)
>>> foo.bars.add(bar)
>>>
>>> # method 2:
>>> foo.bars.add(target_pk) # will work just the same
```

target_pk can also be a string. If you want to add a list of primary keys, you'll have to pass them as arguments, thusly:

```
>>> pk_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> foo.bars.add(*pk_list)
```

This will also work if the items would be strings, i.e. `pk_list = ['1', '2', '3']`. Just remember that if one of the pks is for an object already related you'll get a `UNIQUE constrained failed` error

This will even work if the primary key isn't an integer. Say I define a primary key as a CharField with length of 15, and I have an object who's primary key is 'Lorem Ipsum', doing this:

```
>>> foo.bars.add('Lorem Ipsum')
```

Will work like a charm!

Comment: Nice. Will it work for multiple objects? (Passing in a list of numbers instead of one.) Will it work if the pk is a string rather than an int?

Comment: @RamRachum Yes and yes. but you'll need to pass it as arguments. I've updated the answer to include examples for that as well

Comment: @RamRachum wait, when you say `a string` do you mean `'1'` or do you mean a custom string you are using as a pk?

Comment: I meant a value of a `CharField` that is used as a pk, like `session_key` in `Session`.

Comment: @RamRachum Yeah, it does. I just checked it. Updated answer too. Wooh! I was surprised actually, wasn't sure what to expect...